# Obtaining Text Box Value after Chracter has been Typed in jQuery

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to get the value in a text box after character has been typed in jQuery? I always seem to be missing out on the last character.

Comment: I think I realize my issue. I am registering the keyup and updating this other element. How do I make sure that I update the element after the other element has changed?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textbox').keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use the bind function:

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

```
$('#textBoxId').bind('keyup keypress', function() { 
      //Do you stuff
  });
```

Comment: This is useful if you want the [callback being called twice](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/AZZSr/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#textboxId").keyup(function(){
  $(this).val()
});
```

Comment: You should be using `value` property or `val()`. I answered a question about a bug involved with using `html()` a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try catching both change and keyup event

```
$("#test").bind("onkeyup change",function()
    {dosomething($(this).val())});
```

demo
http://jsfiddle.net/RnPcf/